# HTTP REQUEST HITTING TO LOCAL SERVER//

Tags: rest-api, integration, httprequest

Can we hit a local/private server using IP address with HTTP request in Salesforce ?? or the server should always be public....
can we access a private IP address of local host/server using the HTTP methods that salesforce.com provides. how to hit the local server...

I have make the callout which was written in .Net (hosted on localserver) which will get the data from stored procedure in SQL.

When i was trying to get the data from SQL to Salesforce , i was able to get the data when i was using the advanced rest tool.
But when i tried in salesforce callouts http methods  with end point url after  setting remotesitesetting , i could not get the  data.User-added image  it gives me an error of '503 service unavailable'.

,when i tried to execute a block of code in Salesforce, i  made callout to  the .Net webservice  file  to test the data, i got an error 'Server unavailable,status code = 503'.

My another important question is ''If the Webservice is hosted on the local or intranet, will the salesforce API (which is on the cloud) able to access that webservice

Thanx in advance[image]

Comment: A server has to be accessible via the internet for Salesforce to be able to call it.

Comment: hi thanks for your response,...can you ellobrate it please how to achive it

Answer (score 4):

A *locahost* means *this computer*, and it can access services running locally on your computer and not on internet. And because it's local to your computer and not exposed to internet, you **cannot** connect Salesforce (or any other external services) to any of your local running services.

There are tools which help expose local running servers on public url to be able to make connections. You may like to take a look at [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Comment: any alternate way to connect to the localserver with any authentication or something else to conncet and send request and get responce form the local server which is not hosted publicly

Comment: There’s none. You need to understand how a localhost vs. that on internet works. If you cannot expose your localhost to a publicly accessible ip, there’s no way to achieve it, not only from Salesforce but from any external facing services.